# Animated title in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I can't figure out how to get an animated title working on a FuncAnimation plot (that uses blit). Based on http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/ and [Python/Matplotlib - Quickly Updating Text on Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077017/python-matplotlib-quickly-updating-text-on-axes), I've built an animation, but the text parts just won't animate. Simplified example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

vls = np.linspace(0,2*2*np.pi,100)

fig=plt.figure()
img, = plt.plot(np.sin(vls))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim([0,2*2*np.pi])
#ttl = ax.set_title('',animated=True)
ttl = ax.text(.5, 1.005, '', transform = ax.transAxes)

def init():
    ttl.set_text('')
    img.set_data([0],[0])
    return img, ttl
def func(n):
    ttl.set_text(str(n))
    img.set_data(vls,np.sin(vls+.02*n*2*np.pi))
    return img, ttl

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func,init_func=init,frames=50,interval=30,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

If `blit=True` is removed, the text shows up, but it slows way down. It seems to fail with `plt.title`, `ax.set_title`, and `ax.text`.

Edit: I found out why the second example in the first link worked; the text was inside the `img` part. If you make the above `1.005` a `.99`, you'll see what I mean. There probably is a way to do this with a bounding box, somehow...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [Animating matplotlib axes/ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299943/animating-matplotlib-axes-ticks) and [python matplotlib blit to axes or sides of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844223/python-matplotlib-blit-to-axes-or-sides-of-the-figure)

So, the problem is that in the guts of `animation` where the blit backgrounds are actually saved (line 792 of [animation.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L792)), it grabs what is in the *axes* bounding box. This makes sense when you have multiple axes being independently animated.  In your case you only have one `axes` to worry about and we want to animate stuff *outside* of the axes bounding box.  With a bit of monkey patching, a level of tolerance for reaching into the guts of mpl and poking around a bit, and acceptance of the quickest and dirtyest solution we can solve your problem as such:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

def _blit_draw(self, artists, bg_cache):
    # Handles blitted drawing, which renders only the artists given instead
    # of the entire figure.
    updated_ax = []
    for a in artists:
        # If we haven't cached the background for this axes object, do
        # so now. This might not always be reliable, but it's an attempt
        # to automate the process.
        if a.axes not in bg_cache:
            # bg_cache[a.axes] = a.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(a.axes.bbox)
            # change here
            bg_cache[a.axes] = a.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(a.axes.figure.bbox)
        a.axes.draw_artist(a)
        updated_ax.append(a.axes)

    # After rendering all the needed artists, blit each axes individually.
    for ax in set(updated_ax):
        # and here
        # ax.figure.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
        ax.figure.canvas.blit(ax.figure.bbox)

# MONKEY PATCH!!
matplotlib.animation.Animation._blit_draw = _blit_draw

vls = np.linspace(0,2*2*np.pi,100)

fig=plt.figure()
img, = plt.plot(np.sin(vls))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim([0,2*2*np.pi])
#ttl = ax.set_title('',animated=True)
ttl = ax.text(.5, 1.05, '', transform = ax.transAxes, va='center')

def init():
    ttl.set_text('')
    img.set_data([0],[0])
    return img, ttl

def func(n):
    ttl.set_text(str(n))
    img.set_data(vls,np.sin(vls+.02*n*2*np.pi))
    return img, ttl

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func,init_func=init,frames=50,interval=30,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Note that this may not work as expected if you have more than one axes in your figure.  A much better solution is to expand the `axes.bbox` *just* enough to capture your title + axis tick labels.  I suspect there is code someplace in mpl to do that, but I don't know where it is off the top of my head.

Comment: This works at full speed! Wish it was included in matplotlib, vs. monkey patched, but works well!

Comment: @HenrySchreiner Your edit should have been accepted. (I just re-did it).  If this solved your problem can you accept the answer (the big gray checkbox on the left).

Comment: Ideally, the text bounding box should be used (since it is passed from the animation function), but for some reason it is not being used (even though I think it is in artists). This is a reasonable hack to fix it for now. :) Thanks!

Comment: @HenrySchreiner The animation code is still a little rough around the edges.  There are good reasons for not doing it this way the main code (see my caveats).  If you want to improve this in main line, please do.  They devs on mpl are very friendly.

Comment: If I use `repeat=False` in the `FuncAnimation` call, and then wait until the animation finishes and zoom in somewhere, the drawing disappears.

Comment: I had problems with this workaround, when I tried to return artist objects to blit from multiple axes. In that case some things were not correctly erased.

Comment: How would you set the axis text if you are using an iterator function with funcanimation?  From what I can tell in the docs the iterator returns a tuple of line objects which just plot to the axis.

Comment: Note right now (2023) the relevant line for `_blit_draw` is `1169`, and you need to change twice the `ax.bbox` (in lines `1183` and `1189`) into `ax.figure.bbox` and monkeypatch it in, but apart from that this answer still works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

To add to tcaswell's "monkey patching" solution, here is how you can add animation to the axis tick labels. Specifically, to animate the x-axis, set `ax.xaxis.set_animated(True)` and return `ax.xaxis` from the animation functions.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

def _blit_draw(self, artists, bg_cache):
    # Handles blitted drawing, which renders only the artists given instead
    # of the entire figure.
    updated_ax = []
    for a in artists:
        # If we haven't cached the background for this axes object, do
        # so now. This might not always be reliable, but it's an attempt
        # to automate the process.
        if a.axes not in bg_cache:
            # bg_cache[a.axes] = a.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(a.axes.bbox)
            # change here
            bg_cache[a.axes] = a.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(a.axes.figure.bbox)
        a.axes.draw_artist(a)
        updated_ax.append(a.axes)

    # After rendering all the needed artists, blit each axes individually.
    for ax in set(updated_ax):
        # and here
        # ax.figure.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
        ax.figure.canvas.blit(ax.figure.bbox)

# MONKEY PATCH!!
matplotlib.animation.Animation._blit_draw = _blit_draw

vls = np.linspace(0,2*2*np.pi,100)

fig=plt.figure()
img, = plt.plot(np.sin(vls))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim([0,2*2*np.pi])
#ttl = ax.set_title('',animated=True)
ttl = ax.text(.5, 1.05, '', transform = ax.transAxes, va='center')

ax.xaxis.set_animated(True)

def init():
    ttl.set_text('')
    img.set_data([0],[0])
    return img, ttl, ax.xaxis

def func(n):
    ttl.set_text(str(n))
    vls = np.linspace(0.2*n,0.2*n+2*2*np.pi,100)
    img.set_data(vls,np.sin(vls))
    ax.set_xlim(vls[0],vls[-1])
    return img, ttl, ax.xaxis

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func,init_func=init,frames=60,interval=200,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call

```
plt.draw()
```

After

```
ttl.set_text(str(n))
```

---

Here there is a very simple example of a text-animation inside a figure "without FuncAnimation()". Try it, you will see if it is useful for you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
titles = np.arange(100)
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
for text in titles:
    plt.clf()
    fig.text(0.5,0.5,str(text))
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: That does draw it, but it slows it down the same amount `blit=False` does. I was hoping to just redraw the text.

Comment: Why you don't simply avoid animation and makes your own animation with plt.ion()? With it you have a lot of control, and you are sure what are you doing every frame... Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444655/dynamically-updating-a-graphed-line-in-python/17480397#17480397

Comment: fig=plt.figure()
    img, = plt.plot(np.sin(vls))
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_xlim([0,2*2*np.pi])
    title = ax.text(.5, 1.005, '', transform = ax.transAxes)

    plt.ion()
    for i in range(100):
        img.set_data(vls,np.sin(vls+.02*(i%50)*2*np.pi))
        title.set_text(str(i%50))
        plt.draw()

Comment: I tested that, it's still slow, but I might be able to manually call `canvas.blit`. I thought that animation was a newer/preferred method (over building it manually).

Comment: Ok... I'm not an expert with animation method. Your problem tell me that it's not working very good... or we missed something. I will investigate the performance in the next days... It's a very interesting problem!

Comment: The second example on the first link had something similar to what I'm doing but it worked. It might be because my titles are outside the redrawn 'img' part?...

Comment: Pablo, what you are describing is _exactly_ what the animation module does behind the scenes, except it wraps it all up in a (nominally) easy to use package and gives you things like one line saving to a mp4 and setting up timers to get a given frame rate.  The issue here is getting blitting (which redraws only a sub-set of the artists on top of a fixed base layer) to work, which is _much_ faster than re-drawing all of the elements in the figure.

Comment: If you read the question, you will see that my answer is a valid answer.

Comment: The question is 'how do I make blit work on artists outside of an axes'

Comment: Setting blit=False causes it to work with the original problem code, just slowly, like ion(). But thanks for your help!