# Dynamically update title and text in matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'd like to make an animation with matplotlib.animation that **dynamically** updates text and title assigned to axes in each frame.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

def func(year):
    # do something
    return data # a 1d numpy array for example

def plot_data(year):
    d = func(year)
    ax.set_title(year)
    ax.text(1, 2, year)
    return ax.bar(np.array([1,2]), d) # bar plot

bars = []
for year in years:
    bars.append(plot_data(year))

anim = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, bars)
plt.show()
```

The output contains cluttered titles and texts when displaying the animation. Is there any way to do that?

I'd appreciate any comment of help.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17562747/2666859

Comment: @StanleyR, thanks! but non of the proposed solutions work for me.